# Country based city list selection

Tags: 7, nodes

I can use [hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module but it contains lot of manual work in entering data. I want for all countries their city list. How to do it ?

Is there any module which helps to show city list based on a country selection? Is there a custom way to do it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Address Field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module.  To do just the country and city, you will have to define a plugin.  Look in the `addressfield/plugins/format` directory for examples.

To add the cities, you will have to define a list of cities for each country in the plugin.  You can then format the list and add it to your plugin and you should be good to go.

One advantage of using the Address Field module is that if you do not define a list of cities for a country, users will still be able to input the city themselves.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to create list of cities for Address Field and limit the user to select a city from the list.

Comment: @Raj Did you look at the format plugins in the folder?  If so, and you still don't understand, please post a new question.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have seen the folder and examples but could not figure it out. I have posted a question, kindly check it: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161065/address-field-select-city-from-dropdown-list

Answer (score 2):

[Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) allows you to **import or export** taxonomy from or to a CSV (comma-separated values) file or with a copy-and-paste text.

> It helps you to quick import a non-standardized vocabulary, for
>   example an old thesaurus, a hierarchical taxonomy or a simple list of
>   children, synonyms, descriptions, weights or related terms to terms.

•   import common field types.

•   import repeatable fields.

•   import a hierarchical (tree) or a polyhierarchical vocabulary.

•   import translations.

•   import your hierarchical tree structure and your fields simultaneously (7.x-5.11-dev).

•       export names, fields, tree, translations... to a csv file.

Comment: This could get a little crazy, but you could also try combining this module with Location and Location Taxonomize https://drupal.org/project/location_taxonomize