# How to select an address field city from dropdown list?

Tags: 7, navigation, entities, taxonomy-terms

I am using Address field module to populate address. A requirement needs to limit cities to a particular set, and also countries to particular set too. so I would like to present a set of cities in drop down list based on country selection. From the [answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/80058/11058) I could figure out that something has to be done in plugins but I could not figure out what exactly. If anyone has sample code for city drop down in Address Field modules's plugins it would be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module. Here is an excerpt about it from its project page.

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

So basically you could "start" from a few cities (City 1, City 2, City 3), and whenever somebody needs another one (not in the list yet), they just enter "City 4". Here is a sample about it (just replace "Option" by "City" to get the idea):

[image]

Comment: Any feedback about this answer? did you get it to work?